# Very simple Python (2.7.9) invalid syntax error after if

Tags: python, syntax

Why do I get an 'invalid syntax' error in the following simple cases (in these cases space is always used for indention.  I opened a new console and have included all output.

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> if (True):
...     x=1
... y=2
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    y=2
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> if True:
...     x=1
... y=2
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    y=2
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> if (True):
...     x=1
... else:
...     y=2
... z=3
  File "<stdin>", line 5
    z=3
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> if True:
...     x=1
...     pass
... y=2
  File "<stdin>", line 4
    y=2
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

This seems very odd to me and is rather irritating when I'm pasting into a window.

Thanks

Comment: Control blocks such as `if`, `while`, etc. require an empty line as a termination marker when entered into the console or IDLE. To get around this, simply run your code from a `.py` file, or use [`IPython`](http://ipython.org).

Comment: @MattDMo: make your comment an answer and we can upvote it =)

Comment: @rakslice the question has been marked as a dupe, so I can't. Glad to help, though.